# Send user to create new GitHub Issue with pre-filled bug data

Tags: github

I'd like my program to let the users easily file bugs with as much useful information for me as it relates to their issue.

When the user clicks the "report a bug" menu, a browser will open at, say, [github.com/noamraph/dreampie/issues/new](https://github.com/noamraph/dreampie/issues/new) with info about their environment pre-filled.

Is it possible to do this through GitHub?

Comment: Noam, a little late, but would either of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [query vars](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/new?title=foo&body=bar) to do this.

```
https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/new?title=foo&body=bar
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible and you can even have your users file the bug right from your application if you want to make use of the GitHub API.

Instead of opening a new tab or window, have it open up within your own application and send it through that, collecting the necessary details and logdump generated.

Via the [GitHub API you can create an issue](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) and pre-fill the title and body with what you need to know.

Then, capture the response back from a successful creation and notify yourself. Or check out the Issues tab on your repo as normal after it's created.